# Open file in gedit by using full path

Tags: files, gedit

In the previous versions of gedit, I was able to open the file directly by entering the full path of file in open window dialog box. But now, I have to browse to the folder manually before I can open the file. Is there a way to enable the full path functionality?

Comment: I was having the same problem with nautilus, but I was able to solve it by entering command 

`gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.preferences always-use-location-entry true`

Answer (score 5):

I found the answer. When the open file dialog box is open, pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> opens the  `Enter Location or URL` field in which you can enter the full file path to open the said file directly.

Comment: But why-oh-why is there not a more obvious way to do this thing!!??